# Center a title inside a table

Tags: tables, spacing

my problem is about this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{.4\linewidth}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\begin{document}

    \title{\empty}
    \author{\empty}
    \maketitle

    \begin{table}[h!]
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tabular}{L|L}
                \textbf{P4/1} \newline              
                sudo ifconfig serviciosB down\newline 
                sudo ifconfig serviciosA \newline 172.24.1.1/24 \newline
                sudo route add -net 172.24.2.0/24 gw 172.24.1.222
                & \textbf{P4/3} \newline 
                sudo ifconfig serviciosA down 
                \newline
                sudo ifconfig serviciosB \newline 172.24.2.1/24 \newline
                sudo route add -net 172.24.1.0/24 gw 172.24.2.222 \\  
                \hline
                \textbf{P4/2} \newline 
                sudo ifconfig serviciosB down \newline
                sudo ifconfig serviciosA \newline 172.24.1.2/24 \newline
                sudo route add -net 172.24.2.0/24 gw 172.24.1.222 & \textbf{P4/4} \newline 
                sudo ifconfig serviciosA down \newline
                sudo ifconfig serviciosB \newline 172.24.2.2/24 \newline
                sudo route add -net 172.24.1.0/24 gw 172.24.2.222 \\
            \end{tabular}
        \end{center}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

The issue is that I'd like to center the title in bold (P4/1,P4/2...), but if I include for example `\begin{center} \textbf{P4/1} end{center}` inside the table, there's a lot of space between the beginning of the table and the title.

I hope someone can help me. Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put the titles in their own row and use `multicolumn{1}{c}{bold title}`. Other than that, I defined a `\titlehead` command which does the job:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{.4\linewidth}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}%
\newcommand{\titlehead}[1]{\hfill\textbf{#1}\hfill\null}%

\begin{document}

\title{\empty}
\author{\empty}
\maketitle

\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
        \begin{tabular}{L|L}
            \titlehead{P4/1} \newline
            sudo ifconfig serviciosB down\newline
            sudo ifconfig serviciosA \newline 172.24.1.1/24 \newline
            sudo route add -net 172.24.2.0/24 gw 172.24.1.222
            & \titlehead{\textbf{P4/3}} \newline
            sudo ifconfig serviciosA down
            \newline
            sudo ifconfig serviciosB \newline 172.24.2.1/24 \newline
            sudo route add -net 172.24.1.0/24 gw 172.24.2.222 \\
            \hline
            \titlehead{\textbf{P4/2}} \newline
            sudo ifconfig serviciosB down \newline
            sudo ifconfig serviciosA \newline 172.24.1.2/24 \newline
            sudo route add -net 172.24.2.0/24 gw 172.24.1.222 
            & \titlehead{\textbf{P4/4}} \newline
            sudo ifconfig serviciosA down \newline
            sudo ifconfig serviciosB \newline 172.24.2.2/24 \newline
            sudo route add -net 172.24.1.0/24 gw 172.24.2.222 \\
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

[image]

Note that I've modified the `L` column type for automatic hanging indentation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{array}    % for '\newcolumntype' macro
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for '\RaggedRight' macro
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash%
   \hangafter=1\hangindent=1.5em}p{0.45\linewidth}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.45\linewidth}}
%% two handy shortcut macros:
\newcommand\mC[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C|}{#1}}
\newcommand\mD[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{L|L}
\mC{\textbf{P4/1}} & \mD{\textbf{P4/3}}\\    
sudo ifconfig serviciosB down\newline 
sudo ifconfig serviciosA \newline 
172.24.1.1/24 \newline
sudo route add -net 172.24.2.0/24 gw 172.24.1.222
& 
sudo ifconfig serviciosA down \newline
sudo ifconfig serviciosB \newline 
172.24.2.1/24 \newline
sudo route add -net 172.24.1.0/24 gw 172.24.2.222 \\  
\hline
\mC{\textbf{P4/2}} & \mD{\textbf{P4/4}}\\
sudo ifconfig serviciosB down \newline
sudo ifconfig serviciosA \newline 
172.24.1.2/24 \newline
sudo route add -net 172.24.2.0/24 gw 172.24.1.222 
& 
sudo ifconfig serviciosA down \newline
sudo ifconfig serviciosB \newline 
172.24.2.2/24 \newline
sudo route add -net 172.24.1.0/24 gw 172.24.2.222 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```